# HTML5 & JS: Getting Image Width

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, width

**EDIT:**
I resolved my problem by doing as ***markE*** suggested.
It is of course required to reference the image after it is loaded. By using the *'.onload'* function, I acquire this. Then, to reference the image, I simply type *'this.width'*, since I am in the scope of the image.
**END OF EDIT**

My canvas object has to draw various images. These images are basically the visuals of objects.
When attempting to get the width of an image, I am left with a lousy zero:

```
this.image = new Image();
// src is a parameter to the constructor which this code is run in.
this.image.src = src;
console.log(this.image.width);
```

This code, as I explained, returns zero.

So far, I know that the returned width is based on the initial constructor of the image-- 
in this case, the *'new Image();'* part.
Hence, if nothing is inserted in as a parameter, that counts as zero.

However, if I put e.g.:

```
this.image = new Image(2, 2);
```

.. the returned value of *'this.image.width'* is 2.

**My Question is: How do I reference the width, without knowing it before loading the image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your image size is not known until it's fully loaded and since it loads asynchronously the sizing is not known immediately after .src**

Set the .onload callback and put any code requiring width,height inside that callback:

```
// new-up an image
this.image = new Image();

// set the callback for when the image is fully loaded
this.image.onload=function(){

    // the image is loaded and it's actual size is now known
    console.log(this.width);

}

// src is a parameter to the constructor which this code is run in.
this.image.src = src;
```

Comment: I tried this already, then I got: "Cannot read property 'width' of undefined." Also, the size of the image cannot be known if I have not yet defined what image I am using?

Comment: Ouch, my bad! `this` inside .onload refers to the image object. I've corrected my answer.  *Sorry about that!*